# Copy files after NPM run build VueJs to other folder into Cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, vuejs2

I work with Windows 10 and have installed Vuejs CLI and in a other folder Cordova.

After i run NMP RUN BUILD i want to copy automatic the dist folder to the Cordova folder to generate manual the Android apk.

How can i achieve this automatic when i run npm run build?